# ListView items aren't updating with notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Apparently the `notifyDataSetChanged()` only updates the visible items in the `listview`, I have a system that changes the background color of an item when its clicked (to dkgray), and I set everything else to transparent(the default), however other items that aren't visible remain selected(dkgray) (I only want the currently selected item to be dkgray). Is there a way to force `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update all items.

Here's  example:

```
//makes all item backgrounds transparent
public void resetListViewBackground(){
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){ //parent.getChildCount()
        listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

//reloads the listview
private void reloadListView() {
    listItems.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.invalidateViews();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> notesArrayList = dbTools.getAllNotes();
    for (int i = 0; i < notesArrayList.size(); i++){
        String temp = "";
        if (notesArrayList.get(i).get("note").length() > 51){
            temp = notesArrayList.get(i).get("note").substring(0,50).toString() + "...";
        } else {
            temp = notesArrayList.get(i).get("note").toString();
        }
        listItems.add(temp);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Everywhere I call `resetListViewBackground()`, I call `reloadListView()` after.
And this is what I use to highlight the selected item.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Also, the most common occurrence of this problem is that every 6th item is highlighted. The `listview` only shows about 4 items at a time.

Comment: All I have with adapters is,   listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Make a custom adapter for your list, it occurs due to view recycling. Also notifyDataSetChanged() works only from a UI thread.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what I'd have to do

Comment: pls post your adapter code

Comment: Astral says right, do that and put `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` out of for Statement

Comment: @timeshift117 customadapter and model class should do the trick

Comment: Have you tried to put notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapters getView-method?

Comment: @KailashDabhi, the only adapter stuff I have done is in my above comment. @ Shayan and @ Raghunandan thanks, but I dont really know how to do that, Im guessing you extend some class, but beyond that I dont know

Comment: @astralprojection is right you need to make custom adapter

Comment: I tried what @user2365568 said and it didnt work

Comment: I created a new class, called CustomArrayAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter, and I called notifyDataSetChanged() from getView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getChildCount()` method won't work for all list items as view recycling is done.
Astral is right as he writes in the comments.

1) Create a custom adapter.(See http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)

2)Inside the `onListItemClick` listener's `onItemClick()` method, call your adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method(whenever the user clicks a list item).

I modified the project that I mentioned and posted it on my Dropbox.(Just import it in Eclipse and run).
Check it out at https://www.dropbox.com/s/gchccjzpkxk8n2z/Planets_modified.zip

Comment: Oh, you aren't supposed to extend ArrayAdapter. Thats what I've done

Comment: Yes you should(at least for your current question). Did you read that link I posted? It's pretty customizable once you get how it works. For e.g., I've modified that code so that I can hide/show checkboxes on demand.

Comment: Yeh sorry, just realised that I am supposed to, I just had mine in a completely separate java class file. I'll see if I can get it to work thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you have a separate Java file or not. However, as a quick start, I suggest you to copy that guide as it is and _then_ try to change colors in the `getView()` method of the adapter. Hint: Add a variable in the `class Planet` (in that example )that will hold the background color for the list item. Then, in the `onClick()` method outside the adapter, set your own color.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working, I had to move all of my code from my original itemclicklistener to the new one in the customadapter class

Comment: Don't confuse the `onClickListener` inside the custom adapter with the one outside it, which is a `onItemClickListener`(for `ListView`). The one inside the adapter is only for actions that should be done in response to the Checkbox being clicked/unclicked. The `onItemClickListener` is for actions that should be done regardless of the adapter behaviour. Without more code it's difficult to explain the distinction! Probably try to post the code (and XML) somewhere I could see what you've done so far.

Comment: Here you go, thanks for helping, http://privatepaste.com/35743e3326, its a bit of a mess at the moment sorry, I kind of stopped trying to figure out your way, and was trying to do the same thing except using a scrollbarchange event

Comment: See my updated post for sample code. Is this what you need?
PS: You'll need to modify it further by replacing the input array of planets to your custom `HashMap` that you've used.

Comment: hey, unfortunately i dont think any of this will help, i dont have any checkboxes. the way im checking if something is selected is different (i dont have any object that hols everything), at the moment ive left it as, when the user scrolls, all the highlighting is removed, thanks for helping anyway

Comment: If you're still interested, I would be able to get it to work, if there was a way to tell what items (positions) are showing, because I have stored the item position that is supposed to be selected, and then i could compare the selected position with the position currently on the screen, and im pretty sure that would work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44080/discussion-between-black-stallion-and-timeshift117)

Comment: You might be interested in this, if you have not solved your problem yet: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296